# Windows Phone 8 File System View

Tags: windows-phone

My apologize if this shouldn't be posted here, if it doesn't belong I guess an admin will remove it anyway. But I'm looking for a way into the Windows Phone 8 file system.

When you connect the phone you see basic folders such as Photos and Documents. But I'd like to get access to 'hidden' folders like App data and such...

Is there anyway to do this? I know there's SDK but I believe they require Win8 Pro Edition and I'm running Win 7 Ultimate on my PC.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't work without any type of unlock of your Windows Phone. There aren't any official ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Currently only jail-breaked SAMSUMG ATIVS and HUAWEI W1 can view "hidden" folders like program data...holp that helps...